# Anchor Problem Deploying NFT Program to Devnet

Tags: blockchain, anchor, smartcontracts, solana, anchor-solana

```
Error: Deploying program failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0x1
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

What is this error about? How do I fix it?

I have set the config url to the devnet, and I have already airdropped into my wallet sufficient funds to deploy on the devnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the `"custom program error: 0x1"` error message is another variation of the Insufficient Funds error. Solved this by airdropping my wallet significantly more SOL. To deploy an NFT with Metadata (using Anchor and Metaplex) my transaction used ~4 SOL, far more than I expected.